# Polygon mesh: Compute vertex normals for smooth shading

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, mesh, polygons

[`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html) has a `"SmoothShading"` `PlotTheme` which automatically computes the [`VertexNormals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexNormals.html) to create a nice smooth rendering.  For example:

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading", 
  PrecisionGoal -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

[image: discretized ball with vertex normals]

Suppose that the only data I have available is this:

```
gr = GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[reg], MeshCells[reg, 2]];
```

It looks like this:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], gr}]
```

[image: discretized ball]

Is there built-in functionality which will compute the vertex normals for a mesh like this?

I know that I can make a `MeshRegion` called `reg`, set `"SmoothShading"` on it, convert to `Graphics3D` using `Show`, then extract the options from the contained `GraphicsComplex`: `Cases[Show[reg], GraphicsComplex[_, _, opt___] :> opt, Infinity]`.  But this is a hack and probably unreliable.  What I am looking for is a built-in and easy way to return the vertex normals in a structured form.  I am hoping that this functionality is exposed, I just didn't find it yet.

Comment: So ``VertexNormals -> Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[reg, 0]`` is not what you're looking for? Or is it?

Answer (score 14):

In case the undocumented internal function `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[meshregion, dimension] `` is of use to someone:

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading", 
   PrecisionGoal -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1];
Graphics3D[
    GraphicsComplex[
     MeshCoordinates[reg],
     {EdgeForm[], Thread[MeshCells[reg, 2], Polygon]},
     VertexNormals -> #]
    ] & /@ {Automatic, Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[reg, 0]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Utility function for the following examples:

```
rplot[reg_] := Graphics3D[
   GraphicsComplex[
    MeshCoordinates[reg],
    {EdgeForm[], Thread[MeshCells[reg, 2], Polygon]},
    VertexNormals -> #]
   ] &
```

Examples:

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   RegionUnion[Ball[], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 2]]];
rplot[reg] /@ {Automatic, Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[reg, 0]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (x^2 - y^2)^2 < 4, {x, y, z}];
rplot[reg] /@ {Automatic, Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[reg, 0]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
reg = ConvexHullMesh[RandomPoint[Sphere[], 100]];
rplot[reg] /@ {Automatic, Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[reg, 0]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Where could I find documentation of `Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[meshregion, dimension]` ? What's the meaning of `dimension` ? Perhaps 0: knot-normals, 1: line-normals, ...? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't believe documentation or code is available.  I inferred `dimension` refers to the dimension of the cells for which to return normals, the same as `MeshCells[]`. I believe the normals correspond to, in the same order, the cells returned by `MeshCells[meshregion, dimension]`.

Comment: Thank you for your plausible answer. I'm far away from understanding what a `normal dimension==0` or `normal dimension==3` might be.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `dimension == 0` corresponds to points (vertices).  So it computes the normals at the vertices, which is what is needed for `VertexNormals`. I assume for dim < 2, the normals are computed as averages of the normals of the 2D facets adjoining the cell. `dimension == 3` corresponds to solid cells (e.g. tetrahedra); the normals are undefined if the embedding dimension is `3` as in this Q&A.

Comment: Thanks again. In the case dimension=0 ( surface in 3D) I suppose some kind of geometric averaging ~1/elementarea...

Answer (score 8):

Its not builtin but should work for the input data type you have:

```
meshPoints = MeshPrimitives[reg, 0] /. Point -> Sequence;

polys = MeshPrimitives[reg, 2] /. Polygon -> Sequence;
polysRotated = RotateRight /@ polys;
polyVecs = polys - polysRotated;

surfaceNorms = 
  MapThread[Cross, {polyVecs[[All, 1]], polyVecs[[All, 2]]}]; 

polyVertexes = MeshCells[reg, 2] /. Polygon -> Sequence;

sharedVerticeAssoc = (Flatten /@ 
    Merge[{PositionIndex[polyVertexes[[All, 1]]],
      PositionIndex[polyVertexes[[All, 2]]],
      PositionIndex[polyVertexes[[All, 3]]]}, Identity]); 

SurfaceNormsAdjacentEachVertice = 
  Table[Plus[meshPoints[[i]], #] & /@ 
    surfaceNorms[[sharedVerticeAssoc[i]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[meshPoints]}];

surfaceVectorsatEachVertex = 
  Table[Riffle[
    SurfaceNormsAdjacentEachVertice[[i]], {meshPoints[[i]]}, {1, -2, 
     2}], {i, 1, Length[meshPoints]}];

Graphics3D[{Table[
   Line /@ Partition[surfaceVectorsatEachVertex[[i]], 2], {i, 
    122}], {EdgeForm[None], gr}}]
```

[image]

Of interest, if you compare the output with the undocumented function there is little difference until you look at more complex shapes such as Michael E2's Ball-Cylinder.

Applying my solution produces the following which while similar.... I wonder if the difference is adjustments to the normal to account for the light source or scattering. Or if the objects are being split on detected edges and the outcomes re-normalized?

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[reg], {EdgeForm[],Thread[MeshCells[reg, 2], Polygon]},VertexNormals -> Total /@ SurfaceNormsAdjacentEachVertice]]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I gave a routine for estimating the normals of a closed mesh in [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118283). The method is due to [Nelson Max](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10867651.1999.10487501):

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading",
                               PrecisionGoal -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1];

pts = MeshCoordinates[reg]; tri = MeshCells[reg, 2];

idx = tri[[All, 1]];

(* get neighbors for each vertex *)
nbrs = Table[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[List @@@ First[FindCycle[
             Extract[idx, Drop[SparseArray[Unitize[idx - k],
                                           Automatic, 1]["NonzeroPositions"], None, -1],
                     # /. {k, a_, b_} | {b_, k, a_} | {a_, b_, k} :> (a -> b) &]]]]],
             {k, Length[pts]}];

(* Max's method *)
nrms = Table[Normalize[Total[With[{c = pts[[k]], vl = pts[[#]]}, 
                                  Cross[vl[[1]] - c, vl[[2]] - c]/
                                  ((#.# &[vl[[1]] - c]) (#.# &[vl[[2]] - c]))] & /@
                             Partition[nbrs[[k]], 2, 1, 1],
                             Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]], {k, Length[pts]}];
```

Check:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], GraphicsComplex[pts, tri, VertexNormals -> nrms]}]
```

[image: discretized sphere with vertex normals]

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], GraphicsComplex[pts, Triangle[tri], VertexNormals -> nrms], 
            Arrowheads[Small], 
            MapThread[Arrow[Tube[{#1, #1 + #2/5}, 0.01]] &, {pts, nrms}]}]
```

[image: show the normals]

As noted, the implementation I gave is only intended for closed meshes; some modification is necessary if your mesh has a boundary.