# Why does Plot3D appear to traverse the points twice?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

While plotting a slow to evaluate function and trying to get some sense of progress, I noticed that Mathematica traverses the grid of points twice. Here's the reduced example:

```
points = {};
Dynamic[
 Show[
   ListPlot[Take[points, Max[0, Length@points - 5]], PlotRange -> All],
   ListPlot[
     Take[points, -Min[Length@points, 5]], PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Opacity[0.1], Red]
   ],
   AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
]

Monitor[
  Plot3D[Pause[0.05]; 0, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0], 
 AppendTo[points, {a, b}];
]
```

If you watch the plot, you'll see that the red points move twice over the grid. If you inspect the `plots` variable after plotting, you'll see that not all the points are duplicates: some are offset from their originals by $\sim10^{-8}$.

Why does `Plot3D` do this, even though I asked for `MaxRecursion -> 0`? Is there any way to convince it to only scan the function once (not having to resort to `ListPlot3D` + `Table`)?

Comment: I am not sure why Plot3D does this, but you can avoid repeated evaluation using a memory pattern, e.g. `f[x_, y_] := f[x, y] = ...`.

Comment: Maybe for computing the vertex normals? Try `NormalsFunction -> None` as option.

Comment: Ruslan, very nice animation, btw.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher this appears to be correct. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: 1) The normals require ***3*** function evaluations (computed from finite differences), so that's a lot of overhead for a slow function. 2) You can add `VertexNormals` computed from the plot, instead of from the function, with [``Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130226/polygon-mesh-compute-vertex-normals-for-smooth-shading/130356#130356). It helps to use `Mesh -> All` when converting the plot to a region: `DiscretizeGraphics[Plot[..., Mesh -> All]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the second pass is for computing the vertex normals. At least the behavior of `Plot3D` is quite different (and somewhat erratic) when we set the option `NormalsFunction -> None`.