# The effect of NormalsFunction on the number of function evaluations in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, graphics3d

An interesting issue was raised [in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174682/monitoring-plot3d-with-a-given-number-of-plotpoints#comment458586_174682) to the following question: [Monitoring Plot3D with a given number of plotpoints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174682/27951).

We were discussing the fact that a `Plot3D` expression with options `PlotPoints -> points` and `MaxRecursion -> 0` evaluated the function to be plotted $4 \ \textrm{points}^2$, instead of simply $\textrm{points}^2$ times as I would have expected from the documentation. In fact, the [docs for `PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) state that, with more than one variable, `PlotPoints -> n` specifies that $n$ initial points should be used in each direction. That, together with the `MaxRecursion -> 0` should stop any attempts at further refinement.

Searching this site, I learned that the **extra evaluations are used to calculate the "vertex normals"** (see [Why does Plot3D appear to traverse the points twice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163624/27951) and Henrik's answer there). This can be turned off using `NormalsFunction -> None`.

At first, however, I did not know about `NormalsFunction` and its effect, so I was playing around with a toy example, and I noticed a pattern in the function evaluations within `Plot3D` that had me scratching my head. I time-stamped each function evaluation and kept track of how many there were, as a ratio to `points^2`, which was my expected number of evaluations:

```
points = 100;

timing =
  Module[
    {i, start, results},
    i = 0;
    start = TimeObject[Now];
    results =
      Reap@
       Plot3D[
         1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
         PlotPoints -> points, MaxRecursion -> 0,
         EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{TimeObject[Now], i++/points^2}]
       ];
    {#1 - start, #2}& @@@ results[[2, 1]]
  ];
```

Requesting $100 \times 100 = 10,000$ points is perhaps uncommon, but it is not outside of the realm of possibilities, and it highlights the issue nicely.

I also generated a `timingNoNormals` by adding `NormalsFunction -> None` to the above code, keeping everything else identical. Here are the results, presented graphically:

```
ListLinePlot[
  {timing, timingNoNormals},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameStyle -> Black,
  FrameLabel -> {"time since start (seconds)", "number of evaluation / points^2"},
  PlotLegends -> {"regular Plot3D", "with NormalsFunction -> None"}
]
```

[image: comparison]

Two features here were surprising to me, which lead to my questions:

- I was surprised to find that a good 3/4 of the evaluation time in `Plot3D` seems to be taken up by calculation of the vertex normals. This can use up quite a bit of time for even moderately costly function. **When can we safely turn this "feature" off using** `NormalsFunction -> None`**? Would it be safe to make that option persistent?**
- Additionally, the delay between the first batch of function evaluations and the second, corresponding to that plateau in the blue plot above, was surprising to me. **What is Plot3D doing in between?** Building a `Graphics3D` object?

Comment: It could be useful to additionally speed interactive cases up: `NormalsFunction -> ControlActive[None, Automatic]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I observed that you included a timing *before* the plot, you missed a timing *after* the plot. Moreover, it appeared to me that `TimeObject` has quite an overhead, so in order to get "purer" timings, I replaced it by `AbsoluteTime[]`.  This is what I used for timings:

```
points = 100;
f = {x, y} \[Function] x y;

opts = {PlotPoints -> points, MaxRecursion -> 0};
timing = Module[{i, start, results}, i = 0;
   results = Reap[
     Sow[{start = AbsoluteTime[], i++/points^2}];
     p = Plot3D[f[x,y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
       Evaluate[opts],
       EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{AbsoluteTime[], i++/points^2}]
       ];
     Sow[{AbsoluteTime[], i++/points^2}];
     ];
   {#1 - start, #2} & @@@ results[[2, 1]]];
```

Then I got this

[image]

So it's not for sure that there is no plateau for the normal-free case. I'd say that a major part of the plateaus in the end are due to the mesh lines because they get shorter with `Mesh -> None`. These are the timings without the mesh lines:

[image]

Moreover, there is some time needed to compute the polygon index lists for the final `GraphicsComplex`. This won't need any point evaluations (the points are already evaluated), so this will also contribute the the plateaus.

Notice also the small shift between the yellow and the first blue ramp. This could be the [infamous 50 ms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize) that might be due to compilation of the normal function into `"WVM"`.

In the end, I still wonder what Mathematica is doing with the normal. In particular because you can get rid virtually all the time spent for "computing the vertex normals" by specifying your own `NormalFunction` like this:

```
νf = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[Cross @@ Transpose[D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {{x, y}, 1}]]];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},NormalsFunction -> νf, Evaluate[opts]]
```

[image]

If the function `f` is sufficiently smooth, this will result in a perfect plot and the following timings

[image]

## Addendum

If I needed many plots *quickly*, I would do the following:

```
points = 100;
mesh = {15, 15};
f = {x, y} \[Function] x y;
νf = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[-Cross @@ Transpose[D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {{x, y}, 1}]]];

cfsurface = 
  With[{code = {Compile`GetElement[X, 1], Compile`GetElement[X, 2], 
      f[Compile`GetElement[X, 1], Compile`GetElement[X, 2]]}},
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}}, code, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
   ];
cνf = 
  With[{code = νf[Compile`GetElement[X, 1], Compile`GetElement[X, 2]]},
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}}, code, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> True]
   ];
getQuads = Compile[{{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
   Flatten[Table[
     {m (j - 1) + i, m (j - 1) + i + 1, m j + i + 1, m j + i},
     {j, 1, n - 1}, {i, 1, m - 1}], 1],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

points = 100;
pts2D = Tuples[{Subdivide[-2., 2., points - 1], Subdivide[-2., 2., points - 1]}];
lines = cfsurface@Outer[List, Subdivide[-2., 2., mesh[[1]] - 1], Subdivide[-2., 2., mesh[[2]] - 1]];
Graphics3D[{
  GraphicsComplex[
   cfsurface[pts2D], {EdgeForm[], Orange, Specularity[White, 30], 
    Polygon[getQuads[points, points]]}, 
   VertexNormals -> c\[Nu]f[pts2D]],
  Line@lines,
  Line@Transpose[lines]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

Even with compilation time included, this takes just 0.1 seconds (and about 0.018 seconds without compilation time).

[image]

Comment: This is very nice, thank you!

Comment: You're always welcome!