# Using more CPU power to decrease evaluating time

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

Lets say I wanted to make a highly detailed graph of a 3D function. Generally I use something like

```
Plot3D[(x^2 + y^2)*Sin[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -1/8, 1/8}, {y, -1/8, 1/8}, PlotPoints -> {800, 800}]
```

That literally takes about 2 minutes to evaluate. Looking at the task manager I see that *Mathematica* does not use as much processing power as it could:

[image]

So actually there is no need to make it faster but I wonder if its possible to use mroe processing power.

Answer (score 7):

*(Salvaging from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174828/38178).)*

On my machine, thes following produces the image in about seven seconds. Note that over 95 percent of that time are spent solely by in the frontend, so further optimization is out of reach for me.

```
range = {{-1/8, 1/8}, {-1/8, 1/8}};
plotpoints = {100, 100} 8;
mesh = {16, 16};
f = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[(x^2 + y^2)*Sin[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]];
νf = {x, y} \[Function] 
   Evaluate[-Cross @@ Transpose[D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {{x, y}, 1}]]];

cfsurface = With[{code = {
      Compile`GetElement[X, 1],
      Compile`GetElement[X, 2],
      f[Compile`GetElement[X, 1], Compile`GetElement[X, 2]]}
    },
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}}, code, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]];

cνf = 
  With[{code = νf[Compile`GetElement[X, 1], Compile`GetElement[X, 2]]}, 
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}}, code, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]];

getQuads = 
  Compile[{{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Flatten[Table[{m (j - 1) + i, m (j - 1) + i + 1, m j + i + 1, m j + i}, {j, 1, n - 1}, {i, 1, m - 1}], 1], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];


xran = Sequence @@ N[range[[1]]];
yran = Sequence @@ N[range[[2]]];
xcoords = Subdivide[xran, plotpoints[[1]] - 1];
ycoords = Subdivide[yran, plotpoints[[2]] - 1];
pts2D = Tuples[{xcoords, ycoords}];
xlines = cfsurface@Outer[List, Subdivide[xran, mesh[[2]] - 1], ycoords];
ylines = Transpose@cfsurface@Outer[List, xcoords, Subdivide[yran, mesh[[2]] - 1]];

Graphics3D[{
  GraphicsComplex[
   cfsurface[pts2D],
   {EdgeForm[], Orange, Specularity[White, 30], 
    Polygon[getQuads @@ plotpoints]},
   VertexNormals -> cνf[pts2D]
   ],
  Line@xlines,
  Line@ylines
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I find that plot to be exceptionally beautiful.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it's the specularity...