# What's the default NormalsFunction for ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: graphics3d, parametric-functions

For `Plot3D`, I can use the method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174828/5379) to compute vertex normals,

```
With[{f = Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2]},
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
  NormalsFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[Cross @@ Transpose[D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {{x, y}}]]]]]
 ]
```

I wonder how to compute vertex normals for `ParametricPlot3D`, I've tried

```
With[{para = {Sin[u] Cos[v] , Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}},
 ParametricPlot3D[para, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  NormalsFunction -> 
   Function[{u, v}, Evaluate[Cross @@ Transpose[D[para, {{u, v}}]]]]]
 ]
```

It looks bad. Do you know how the default `NormalsFunction` is defined, or how can I define a suitable function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is correct, but a problem with the code arises because `With[]` causes the literally-appearing parameters of `Function[]` to have a `$` added to them, but not those in `para`. The result is that the normal is the zero vector at all points.  Also check the arguments to `Function` for a `NormalsFunction` for `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

Try it this way:

```
With[{para = {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}},
 ParametricPlot3D[para, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> None,
  NormalsFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, #] &[
     Cross @@ Transpose[D[para, {{u, v}}]]])]]
```