# Extracting Internal Visualization Information (PlotTheme, MeshRegion, FaceNormals, etc.)

Tags: visualization, mesh, plot-themes, internals

Sometimes, you can tell *Mathematica* knows something internally, possibly because it visualizes the known quantities for you, but can't figure out how to get it to tell you them explicitly.  I'm having such a problem with `MeshRegion` and certain `PlotThemes`.

Say you have a mesh - say this one from the documentation:

```
 myMesh = 
   MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 2}},
    {Tetrahedron[{1, 2, 3, 5}], Tetrahedron[{1, 3, 4, 5}]}];
```

You can then request to **see** the normal vectors of each face using `PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"` like this:

```
 MeshRegion[myMesh, PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"]
```

This produces the requested tetrahedron with small, black lines visualizing the face normal vectors.

However, I cannot seem to find how to have *Mathematica* print this information explicitly.  I have tried using `MeshRegion[myMesh, PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"] // InputForm` and deducing from this, but it simply repeated that my requested PlotTheme is "FaceNormals", without the numerical information for the vector visualizations.

I have dug for it, but feel I may be missing some portion of the documentation where this is stated. Does anyone know how to - either by extracting it from *Mathematica's* internal workings, or simply mathematically in an algorithmic fashion - produce the "FaceNormals" of any arbitrary mesh?

My actual meshes aren't so simple as they vary in shape and have upwards of 1000 triangular faces or more, rather than the 4 here, but the `PlotTheme` itself produces the "FaceNormals" with no issue, so I know it can be done and has internally...

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130356/4999 for ``Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals``

Comment: also `mr= MeshRegion[myMesh, PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"];
facenormals=Cases[Normal[Show@mr], _Line, Infinity];
Show[mr, Graphics3D[{Red, Thick,facenormals}]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mr = MeshRegion[myMesh, PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"];
fnormals = Cases[Normal[Show @ mr], _Line, Infinity];

Show[mr, Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, fnormals}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[mr, Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, fnormals /. Line[{x_, y_}] :> Line[{x, x + 10 (y-x)}]}]]
```

[image]