# Why are there speckles on the surface generated by ListContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
ListContourPlot3D[
 Table[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -1, 1, 0.02}, {y, -1, 1, 0.02}, {z, -1, 1,
    0.02}], Contours -> {1}, Mesh -> None]
```

will generate plot as below

[image]

Notice the red circles. Why are there speckles on the surface? How to remove them and get a perfect surface?

Comment: I doubt that you will ever get a perfect surface; however, I suggest that you start with the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for reply. But `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` has no effect at all.

Comment: ```MaxPlotPoints ->60``` ? The default is Infinity.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for reply. `MaxPlotPoints ->60` seems works. But why does it work?

Comment: No idea. In the Details section for `MaxPlotPoints` it says, "With finite settings for MaxPlotPoints, the total number of points plotted is reduced by combining nearby points." Since there were only two settings, I applied the other one to see what would happen.

Answer (score 5):

The second update at the end is probably the best solution when `ListContourPlot3D` produces bad shading.

*First answer, with update*

One source of strange shading is bad `VertexNormals`. They have to be estimated from the data, and if they "wobble" from true normal, the surface's shading changes slightly.

On the test example, we "know" what the surface normal should be.  We fix it to show that it fixes the shading.  For real data, it seems unusual to know how calculate exactly the normals.

```
GraphicsRow[{
  foo = ListContourPlot3D[Table[x^2 + y^2 + z^2,
     {x, -1, 1, 0.02}, {y, -1, 1, 0.02}, {z, -1, 1, 0.02}],
    Contours -> {1}, Mesh -> None], 
  foo /. 
   GraphicsComplex[p_, a___, HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> _], b___] :>
     GraphicsComplex[p, a, 
     VertexNormals -> Transpose[Transpose@p - 50], b]
  },
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

These are easier ways to fix it, ***but*** (*update*) they just remove the vertex normals, which I didn't notice because of the fineness of the mesh:

```
DeleteCases[foo, HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> _], Infinity]
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeGraphics[foo]]
(* each produces graphics like this: *)
```

[image]

A way to get the normals from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130356/4999) is not so simple, but closed surfaces even when their equations are unknown.

```
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[foo];
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[mesh],
  {First[
    "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
       Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, RegionPlot3D])],
   EdgeForm[], Thread[MeshCells[mesh, 2], Polygon]}, 
  VertexNormals -> Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[mesh, 0]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

*Update 2*

This does a better job than `ListContourPlot3D`, but I thought it was basically equivalent to it.  It makes the OP's issue seem like a bug in `ListContourPlot3D`:

```
ifn = ListInterpolation[Table[x^2 + y^2 + z^2,
    {x, -1, 1, 0.02}, {y, -1, 1, 0.02}, {z, -1, 1, 0.02}]];
ContourPlot3D[ifn[x, y, z], {x, 1, 101}, {y, 1, 101}, {z, 1, 101}, 
 Contours -> {1}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael E2. The GraphicsComplex replacement stuff works like a magic. But forgive my slow mind, I do not quite understand what is going on in this replacement, why it works? And what do you mean by "For real data, it seems unusual to know how calculate exactly the normals."  I tried `x^2 + y^2 - z^2`, also works great. Why doesn't mathematica take this procedure into standard `ListContourPlot3D`? It seems unreasonable to me that `ListContourPlot3D` can not produce a simple sphere well.

Comment: @matheorem The replacement sets the `VertexNormals` to the surface normals calculated from the formula, which is simple for a sphere. `ListContourPlot3D` does not know the equation `x^2 + y^2 + z^2`. Most data does not come from known symbolic equations. When the equation is known, `ContourPlot3D` is the normal choice and uses the procedure.  You might report it to WRI to see if they want to look into whether it's a bug or just unavoidable numerical noise.