# Calculating Gaussian Curvature for an irregular surface

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, code-request, differential-geometry

Below is an irregular surface generated from large data and plotted with `ListSurfacePlot3D` [from this data file](https://pastebin.com/raw/bQMUDFLs) using columns {3,4,2}.
[image: surface plot]

I would like to calculate the Gaussian and mean curvatures along with principal curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$. Is this possible with Wolfram ? Any advice or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: is this contour defined to be the contour of a function?

Comment: is this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118283/1089 not helping?

Comment: @chris, my answer there as currently implemented is only good for *closed* meshes. The routines there need to be (heavily!) modified for a surface like the OP's.

Comment: I can close the surface on the edges...and to follow @chris's link..I am struggling to define an implicit region for this model.