# Mean curvature calculation of a mesh (Surface Evolver)

Tags: mesh, discrete, curvature

I'm trying to calculate the mean curvature over the surface of a discrete mesh that I generated from the computational software SE (Surface Evolver) and I want to make sure I can calculate the same curvature energy I got from SE.

In SE, I used the built-in function *star_perp_sq_mean_curvature* to calculate the curvature energy. There is a software manual
https://kenbrakke.com/evolver/html/quants.htm#star_perp_sq_mean_curvature
however, I think a lot of details are under the hood.

What I want to understand is,

1. this 30 yo software calculates the curvature energy in a flash second while my code takes mins
2. when the surface of the mesh is pretty smooth, the value I calculate is not much different from that of SE but once the mesh has some locally sharp patches, the calculation becomes quite off from SE

I think there are a lot of ways to approximate the mean curvature, for instance, the method here
[How to speed up estimation of Mean and Gaussian curvatures on triangular meshes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117884/how-to-speed-up-estimation-of-mean-and-gaussian-curvatures-on-triangular-meshes)
works pretty well but not as fast as SE does and the numbers are not the same.

Maybe I will have to open up the hood to completely mimic the calculation, but I wonder in case, if anyone knows how to code the mean curvature calculation that gives the same number with SE,
or
if there is a way to calculate the mean curvature of a mesh with ~10^4 vertices in a second with a good approximation level.

Comment: Is this a question about Wolfram Mathematica? Because there is no code or anything similar ... You have to at least provide a small example of a mesh and the expected result.

Comment: The 30 year old software was coded in portable C and was designed by people who knew what they were doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what the Surface Evolver does, but the following should be a quite quick an appropriate approximation of the squared mean curvature integral. Note that I am using code from this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/38178.

```
(*Assuming that S is a MeshRegion that represents a _closed_ triangle surface with consistent orientation of triangles.*)
pts = MeshCoordinates[S];
flist = MeshCells[S, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
pat = Flatten[getLaplacianCombinatorics[flist], 1];
A = LaplaceBeltrami[pts, Flatten[flist], pat];

Block[{i, j, k, U1, U2, U3, V1, V2, V3},
  {i, j, k} = Transpose[flist];
  {U1, U2, U3} = Transpose[pts[[j]] - pts[[i]]];
  {V1, V2, V3} = Transpose[pts[[k]] - pts[[i]]];
  
  triangleareanormals = 
   0.5 Transpose[{U2 V3 - U3 V2, U3 V1 - U1 V3, U1 V2 - U2 V1}];
  
  triangleareas = Sqrt[Total[triangleareanormals^2, {2}]];
];


Av = With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"],
    vals = ConstantArray[(1/3.), 3 Length[flist]],
    pat = Transpose[{
       Flatten[flist],
       Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[Range[Length[flist]], 3]]]
       }]
    }, 
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" ->{"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}], 
      SparseArray[Rule[pat, vals], {Length[pts], Length[flist]}, 0.],
      SetSystemOptions[spopt]
     ]
   ];



vertexareas = Av . triangleareas;

vertexinvareas = 1./vertexareas;

vertexnormals = (Av.triangleareanormals) vertexinvareas;

A = LaplaceBeltrami[pts, Flatten[flist], pat];

H = 0.5 ((A.pts) vertexinvareas);

Hproj = vertexnormals Total[vertexnormals H, {2}] / Total[vertexnormals^2, {2}];

HSquareIntegral = Total[H^2, {2}] . vertexareas;
HprojSquareIntegral = Total[Hproj^2, {2}] . vertexareas;
```

Here `A` is the weak formulation of the Laplace-Betrami operator, `pts` are the vertex coordinates and `A.pts` is *exactly* the derivative of the the surface area with respect to all the vertex coordinates. `H` is therefore an approximation of the $L^2$-gradient of surface area; hence one of many possible approximations of the mean curvature vector field.

Surface Evolver seems to project this onto the $L^2$-gradient of the volume functional which is typically a good approximation for vertex normals. I think this just the area-weigted normals, but I could be wrong.

This runs on my machine for a mesh with 1.5 million triangles in about 0.85 seconds. It does some superfluous work though (one does not really have to compute the Laplace-Beltrami operator), and coding this in a low-level language like C++ and using parallelization, one can get this below a quarter of a second or less.

Note that no discretization is perfect. (Some are way worse than others, though.) Almost all have defects when applied to unsmooth meshes. So keeping your meshes in a good state (for example, by remeshing) is pivotal.

Comment: wow I got really impressed about the speed! Thanks a lot!
However, I am having some trouble connecting this to the continuum curvature energy
Could you help me a bit with this?
I thought HprojSquareIntegral in this code is supposed to approximate the area integral of mean curvature square
So it should output 8Pi for a sphere but it seems like to be about 1/5 of 8Pi? Am I missing something or totally misunderstanding?
Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! The sphere has area $4 \pi$ and mean curvature $1$. So the energy should be $4 \pi \approx 12.5664$. My code deviates from this for two reasons: 1.) I forgot to divide my `H` by `0.5`. 2.) In the definition of `Av` I divided by `.3` instead of `3.` ^^  Now for a nice sphere mesh with 82000 triangles, I get a relative error of `0.0000726882` for the energy.

Comment: Oh yeah, 4Pi! I multiplied the conventional prefactor for the curvature energy (Helfrich). The bare integral has to be 4Pi. Thanks for fixing it!